# Pass array of taxonomy terms to wp_query

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, query, terms

I am trying to compile an array of taxonomies and terms to pass to wp_query, my array looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => color
            [field] => term_id
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => shape
            [field] => term_id
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 87
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => weight
            [field] => term_id
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 54
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [taxonomy] => rating
            [field] => term_id
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 87
                    [1] => 88
                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to pass it to wp_query like this...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'tax_query' => $myarray,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This is not giving me any results, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is ambiguity, you can't just put in `'relation' => 'OR'` in the main parameter list, because how would `WP_Query` know if it's for the `tax_query` and not the `meta_query`?

For how it's supposed to work, and where the `relation` parameter goes we need to refer to [the official docs for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) which gives us this example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'quotes' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote' ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Setting it may be as simple as:

```
$myarray['relation'] = 'OR'; // untested
```